# Views not being displayed in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I have a ViewController, called "TapRaceViewController" which inherits from the parent, "GameViewCController". However, none of TapRaceViewControllers subviews are being displayed - only the views from GameController are being displayed. Why is that? TapRacerViewController's viewDidLoad is being called, so I don't see why the subviews are not being added in.

```
//
//  TapRacerViewController.h
//  MiniGame
//
//  Created by Software Engineering on 11/16/14.
//
//

#import "GameViewController.h"

@interface TapRacerViewController : GameViewController

@end
```

TapRacerViewController.m

```
//
//  TapRacerViewController.m
//  MiniGame
//
//  Created by Software Engineering on 11/16/14.
//
//

#import "TapRacerViewController.h"

@interface TapRacerViewController ()

@end

@implementation TapRacerViewController
{
    //A single tap on the screen
    UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap;

    //the player
    UILabel* player;

    //The view
    UIView* m_baseView;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Create the base view
    m_baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [m_baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:m_baseView];

    //Create the tap gesture
    singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap)];
    [m_baseView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    //Create the player
    player = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 50, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2, 50, 50)];
    [player setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [m_baseView addSubview:player];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Handles a tap
- (void) handleSingleTap
{
    NSLog(@"Tap!");
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

And the GameViewController,

```
//
//  GameViewController.h
//  MiniGame
//
//  Created by Software Engineering on 11/16/14.
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GameViewController : UIViewController
//Base init
-(id) initWithDifficulty:(int)difficulty;

//On each tick
-(void) onTick;

@end
```

GameViewController.m

```
//
//  GameViewController.m
//  MiniGame
//
//  Created by Software Engineering on 11/16/14.
//
//

#import "GameViewController.h"

@interface GameViewController ()

@end

@implementation GameViewController
{
    //Timer
    NSTimer* m_timer;
    //Counter of the timer
    float m_timerCounter;
    //How long the minigame lasts
    float m_time;

    //Base view
    UIView* m_baseView;


    //How often a tick occurs
    float m_tick;
    //Text that tells the user what to do
    UILabel* m_instructionLabel;
}

//Base initialization
-(id) initWithDifficulty:(int)difficulty
{
    NSLog(@"Heyea");
    //Base initialization
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        if(difficulty == 1)
        {
            m_time = 5.0f;
        }
        else if(difficulty == 2)
        {
            m_time = 4.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            m_time = 3.0f;
        }

        //Set the timer counter to 0.0f;
        m_timerCounter = 0.0f;

        //Set the tick frequency to 0.001f;
        m_tick = 0.001f;

        //Set the base view
        m_baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
        [m_baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:m_baseView];


        //Set the default instruction text
        m_instructionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
        [m_instructionLabel setText:@"Instruction!"];
        [m_instructionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-BoldItalic" size:15.0]];
        [m_instructionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [m_baseView addSubview:m_instructionLabel];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

//When the view loads, start the countdown
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //Start the timer
    m_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:m_tick target:self selector:@selector(onTick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//On every tick from m_timer
- (void)onTick
{
   // NSLog(@"Tick!");
   // NSLog(@"%.2f", m_timerCounter);

    //Incriment the alpha of the text
    if(m_instructionLabel.alpha > 0.7) {
        [m_instructionLabel setAlpha:m_instructionLabel.alpha - 0.001];
    }
    //Incriment the timer counter by a tick
    m_timerCounter += m_tick;
    //If the timer counter is more than the alloted time for the mini game, quit the mini game
    if(m_timerCounter > m_time)
    {
        //Stop the timer
        [m_timer invalidate];
        m_timer = nil;

        //Dismiss this view controller
        [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }

}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Ummm. You didn't add `m_baseView` to `self.view`'s subviews?

Comment: try adding m_baseView on TapRacerViewController

Comment: Thought I put it back in there before posting. Nice try guys, but it doesn't show. Updated code to prevent further confusion.

Comment: Have you tried using the views debugger on Xcode 6? And try moving the views construction code to `viewDidAppear`, any differences? Also, what is the value of `self.view.bounds` in `viewDidLoad` in `TapRaceViewController`? And I think using the same instance variable names in both parent and subclass is not really a good idea. Though it might not be the reason why it didn't work.

Comment: @SikhapolSaijit Hm, weird. It works in viewDidAppear. But now it does not disappear after 5.0 seconds. Why would it work in viewDidAppear and not viewDidLoad? And why is it not exciting?
EDIT: Silly me, didn't call [super viewDidAppear:NO] in the TapGameViewController. Doesn't explain why it works in viewDidAppear and not viewDidLoad

Comment: So, I think the views are actually added to the tree. But `self.view.bounds.size` is definitely equal to zero in `viewDidLoad`. When you create `m_baseView` bases on that information it's size is also zero. I don't know why this happens. But if you use auto layout. The constraints aren't applied until the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called. But what surprised me was that views you added in `GameViewController` are actually displayed. Because at that point, `self.view` should still be `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't added the view to it's super View I guess.

```
[self.view addSubview:m_baseView];
```

Write this line at the end of your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Whoops, thought I put it back in there before I posted this. Updated. It still doesn't show the new m_baseView.

Comment: Try changing the names of the iVars. Check.